# Macro to insert Rows and populate

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data pictured below, that I want to conditionally filter. Specifically, on the Amount column - if a cell value is 197, I want to be able to insert 2 blank rows below it and populate it with either exact copies of data in original row or a simple formula incrementing the timestamp.

[image: Data Set/Table]

I'm not really familiar with VBA objects, so I've been looking all over and trying different things, but I feel like I might be missing something obvious here. In the next 2 rows created, I want to increment the timestamp (Created (UTC) column) by exactly one month for each row, and copy all the other data. I'm not sure how to write a Macro that populates, and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

Make sure you run it with the sheet you want to update active (it uses `ActiveSheet`)

```
Sub InsertAndUpdate()
Dim x As Long
For x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(x, "B").Value = 197 Then
        Cells(x + 1, "B").EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(x + 1, "B").EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(x, "B").EntireRow.Copy Cells(x + 1, "B").EntireRow
        Cells(x, "B").EntireRow.Copy Cells(x + 2, "B").EntireRow
        Cells(x + 1, "A").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(x + 1, "A").Value)
        Cells(x + 2, "A").Value = DateAdd("m", 2, Cells(x + 2, "A").Value)
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

You can also shorten it a bit like this, but using a nested loop for something so simple is kinda meh

```
Sub InsertAndUpdate()
Dim x As Long, y As Integer
For x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(x, "B").Value = 197 Then
        For y = 1 To 2
            Cells(x + y, "B").EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(x, "B").EntireRow.Copy Cells(x + y, "B").EntireRow
            Cells(x + y, "A").Value = DateAdd("m", y, Cells(x + y, "A").Value)
        Next y
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

**Results (With added rows highlighted by me)**

[image: Results]